# How to append a class based on a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a chessboard, which this code does. However, I don't know how to add the rows and columns (eg. a1, g3...) to each individual space as a class. I would like to use the j variable in the for loop for the numbers, and then something like column[counter] to add the row. Roughly something like this; class = "column[counter]+j". I know this syntax won't work, So I'm wondering, is there a way to do this the way I'm trying? Thanks, any help appreciated.

```
 $(function(){
  var counter = 0,
  var column = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
  for(i=0;i<8;i++) {
    if (i%2==0) {
      for (j=0;j<8;j++) {
        $('.chessboard').append("<div class='space even'></div>");

      }
    } else {
      for (j=0;j<8;j++) {
        $('.chessboard').append("<div class='space odd'></div>");
      }
    counter ++
  }
});
```

Comment: What are you using the classes for? It's entirely possible that, based on CSS3 selectors, you don't actually need to add classes, and could instead use a selector like `div.space:even`.

Comment: Have a look at [**string concatenation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators).

Comment: Eventually I'll have to target each individual space for game logic, I'm using odd and even classes for the alternating colors.

Comment: Anytime I add code inside append() it returns a string. I'm trying to dynamically change the class on the fly based on the j variable and the counter to produce classes: a1, a5, g4, ect...Is this possible when using append?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cleaned up the javascript a little to give you a good base to build on.  Leveraging jQuery to add classes instead of appending strings is a nice way to keep things simple.

```
$(function(){  
    var column = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'];
    for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {    
        for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            var tile = $("<div class='space'></div>");

            //add even or odd class
            tile.addClass( i % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd' );          

            //add name of tile class
            tile.addClass(column[i] + (j + 1));

            $('.chessboard').append(tile);
        }
    } 
});
```

Comment: I like this improved approach from concatenation spaghetti into `addClass`

Comment: Really like the refactored code, I'm still learning so doing it like this didn't occur to me. I like how all the logic takes place before its appended. Easier to read. Much appreciated!

Comment: @AnthonyD : For a solution that's both performance optimized and easy to style, I'd recommend my second solution @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781109/how-to-append-a-class-based-on-a-variable/34781240#34781240 (see also https://jsfiddle.net/2gxLhnb6/10/ for a demo).

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to achieve what you're looking for :

```
$(function(){
    var column = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'];
    var $chessboard = $('.chessboard');
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        for (j=0;j<8;j++)
            $chessboard.append("<div class='" +
                               column[i] + "-" + j +
                               (j%2===0 ? " evencol" : " oddcol") +
                               (i%2===0 ? " evenrow" : " oddrow") +
                               "'></div>");
});
```

It generates the following HTML :

```
<div class="a-0 evencol evenrow"></div>
<div class="a-1 oddcol evenrow"></div>
<div class="a-2 evencol evenrow"></div>
<div class="a-3 oddcol evenrow"></div>
<div class="a-4 evencol evenrow"></div>
<div class="a-5 oddcol evenrow"></div>
<div class="a-6 evencol evenrow"></div>
<div class="a-7 oddcol evenrow"></div>
<div class="b-0 evencol oddrow"></div>
<div class="b-1 oddcol oddrow"></div>
<div class="b-2 evencol oddrow"></div>
<div class="b-3 oddcol oddrow"></div>
<div class="b-4 evencol oddrow"></div>
<div class="b-5 oddcol oddrow"></div>
<div class="b-6 evencol oddrow"></div>
<div class="b-7 oddcol oddrow"></div>
<div class="c-0 evencol evenrow"></div>
<div class="c-1 oddcol evenrow"></div>
<div class="c-2 evencol evenrow"></div>
<div class="c-3 oddcol evenrow"></div>
<div class="c-4 evencol evenrow"></div>
<div class="c-5 oddcol evenrow"></div>
<div class="c-6 evencol evenrow"></div>
<div class="c-7 oddcol evenrow"></div>
<div class="d-0 evencol oddrow"></div>
<div class="d-1 oddcol oddrow"></div>
<div class="d-2 evencol oddrow"></div>
<div class="d-3 oddcol oddrow"></div>
<div class="d-4 evencol oddrow"></div>
<div class="d-5 oddcol oddrow"></div>
<div class="d-6 evencol oddrow"></div>
<div class="d-7 oddcol oddrow"></div>
<div class="e-0 evencol evenrow"></div>
<div class="e-1 oddcol evenrow"></div>
<div class="e-2 evencol evenrow"></div>
<div class="e-3 oddcol evenrow"></div>
<div class="e-4 evencol evenrow"></div>
<div class="e-5 oddcol evenrow"></div>
<div class="e-6 evencol evenrow"></div>
<div class="e-7 oddcol evenrow"></div>
<div class="f-0 evencol oddrow"></div>
<div class="f-1 oddcol oddrow"></div>
<div class="f-2 evencol oddrow"></div>
<div class="f-3 oddcol oddrow"></div>
<div class="f-4 evencol oddrow"></div>
<div class="f-5 oddcol oddrow"></div>
<div class="f-6 evencol oddrow"></div>
<div class="f-7 oddcol oddrow"></div>
<div class="g-0 evencol evenrow"></div>
<div class="g-1 oddcol evenrow"></div>
<div class="g-2 evencol evenrow"></div>
<div class="g-3 oddcol evenrow"></div>
<div class="g-4 evencol evenrow"></div>
<div class="g-5 oddcol evenrow"></div>
<div class="g-6 evencol evenrow"></div>
<div class="g-7 oddcol evenrow"></div>
<div class="h-0 evencol oddrow"></div>
<div class="h-1 oddcol oddrow"></div>
<div class="h-2 evencol oddrow"></div>
<div class="h-3 oddcol oddrow"></div>
<div class="h-4 evencol oddrow"></div>
<div class="h-5 oddcol oddrow"></div>
<div class="h-6 evencol oddrow"></div>
<div class="h-7 oddcol oddrow"></div>
```

Now, just add a few lines of CSS, and your result should look like this :

[image]

See [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2gxLhnb6/9/) for a demo.

---

**Alternative implementation :**

An alternative approach would be to do this :

```
$(function(){
    var column = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'];
    var currentRow;
    var $chessboard = $('.chessboard');
    for(i=0;i<8;i++) {
        currentRow = $("<div class='" + (i%2===0 ? " even" : " odd") + "'></div>").appendTo($chessboard);
        for (j=0;j<8;j++) {
            currentRow.append("<div class='" + column[i] + "-" + j + (j%2===0 ? " even" : " odd") + "'></div>");
        }
    }
});
```

It generates the following HTML :

```
<div class="even">
    <div class="a-0 even"></div>
    <div class="a-1 odd"></div>
    <div class="a-2 even"></div>
    <div class="a-3 odd"></div>
    <div class="a-4 even"></div>
    <div class="a-5 odd"></div>
    <div class="a-6 even"></div>
    <div class="a-7 odd"></div>
</div>
<div class="odd">
    <div class="b-0 even"></div>
    <div class="b-1 odd"></div>
    <div class="b-2 even"></div>
    <div class="b-3 odd"></div>
    <div class="b-4 even"></div>
    <div class="b-5 odd"></div>
    <div class="b-6 even"></div>
    <div class="b-7 odd"></div>
</div>
<div class="even">
    <div class="c-0 even"></div>
    <div class="c-1 odd"></div>
    <div class="c-2 even"></div>
    <div class="c-3 odd"></div>
    <div class="c-4 even"></div>
    <div class="c-5 odd"></div>
    <div class="c-6 even"></div>
    <div class="c-7 odd"></div>
</div>
<div class="odd">
    <div class="d-0 even"></div>
    <div class="d-1 odd"></div>
    <div class="d-2 even"></div>
    <div class="d-3 odd"></div>
    <div class="d-4 even"></div>
    <div class="d-5 odd"></div>
    <div class="d-6 even"></div>
    <div class="d-7 odd"></div>
</div>
<div class="even">
    <div class="e-0 even"></div>
    <div class="e-1 odd"></div>
    <div class="e-2 even"></div>
    <div class="e-3 odd"></div>
    <div class="e-4 even"></div>
    <div class="e-5 odd"></div>
    <div class="e-6 even"></div>
    <div class="e-7 odd"></div>
</div>
<div class="odd">
    <div class="f-0 even"></div>
    <div class="f-1 odd"></div>
    <div class="f-2 even"></div>
    <div class="f-3 odd"></div>
    <div class="f-4 even"></div>
    <div class="f-5 odd"></div>
    <div class="f-6 even"></div>
    <div class="f-7 odd"></div>
</div>
<div class="even">
    <div class="g-0 even"></div>
    <div class="g-1 odd"></div>
    <div class="g-2 even"></div>
    <div class="g-3 odd"></div>
    <div class="g-4 even"></div>
    <div class="g-5 odd"></div>
    <div class="g-6 even"></div>
    <div class="g-7 odd"></div>
</div>
<div class="odd">
    <div class="h-0 even"></div>
    <div class="h-1 odd"></div>
    <div class="h-2 even"></div>
    <div class="h-3 odd"></div>
    <div class="h-4 even"></div>
    <div class="h-5 odd"></div>
    <div class="h-6 even"></div>
    <div class="h-7 odd"></div>
</div>
```

With some slight differences in your CSS (compared with the other option, your result should also look like this :

[image]

See [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2gxLhnb6/10/) for a demo.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, much appreciated. I chose IrkenIvaders answer because I found it easier to read. Thanks again!

Comment: @AnthonyD IrkenIvader's answer may be more readable, but my answer is optimised for performance AND HTML output is easier to style with CSS (see https://jsfiddle.net/2gxLhnb6/9/). Also, there's the alternative answer, which generates more readable HTML code.